# Edit column data at SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update my retrieved data as described below:

```
  UPDATE vw_public_task_priority 
  SET task_state = REPLACE(task_state, 'NULL', 'DONE')
```

After I execute it I get the next error:

> Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>
> Update or insert of view or function `'vw_public_task_priority'`
>   failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Can you please advice to me what I'm doing wrong + there is a possibility to update the results at new column instead of edit `"task_state"` data?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually trying to replace the word 'NULL' with text or are you trying to update fields that have not data in them (proper NULL fields) with a value? They're two very different things

Comment: Can you add the `Views` definition

Comment: `update public_task_priority set task_state = 'DONE' where task_state is null`. (If the view is updatable.)

Comment: You're right, Null means fields that have not data in them.
What you mean by adding views definition ?

Comment: as mentioned by Rich if these are actual null values and not the text "NULL"  depending on RDBMS which you didn't mention you could do something like  UPDATE vw_public_task_priority
   SET task_state = NVL (task_state, 'DONE');

Comment: Its looks like I cannot update it.
Can I paste the "New" data at new column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE vw_public_task_priority SET task_state = 'DONE' where task_state is null
```

Comment: I tried it too without successes.

There is a possibility to make all required changes in new column?
That way we will not need to change data at DB.